# Killing spark streaming job when no activity

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to kill my spark streaming job when there is no activity (i.e. the receivers are not receiving messages) for a certain time. I tried doing this

```
var counter = 0

myDStream.foreachRDD {
  rdd =>
    if (rdd.count() == 0L)
    {
      counter = counter + 1
      if (counter == 40) {
        ssc.stop(true, true)
      }
    } else {
      counter = 0
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? How would I make a variable available to all receivers and update the variable by 1 whenever there is no activity?

Answer (score 2):

Use a NoSQL Table like Cassandra or HBase to keep the counter. You can not handle Stream Polling inside a loop. Implement same logic using NoSQL or Maria DB and perform a Graceful Shutdown to your streaming Job if no activity is happening.
The way I did it was I maintained a Table in Maria DB for Streaming JOB having Polling interval of 5 mins. Every 5 mins it hits the data base and writes the count of records it consumed also the method returns what is the count of zero records line items during latest timestamp. This helped me a lot managing my Streaming Job Management. Also this table usually helps me o automatically trigger the Streaming job based on a logic written in a shell script

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it. I was thinking of doing it via broadcast variables. Feel free to pass on your suggestions.

Comment: Broadcast is an immutable variable. Once broadcasted can not be updated, can not be updated. Accumulator you can try.